# Pandas df.at() raising AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a relatively huge dataframe. Im trying to iterate to each row and update a column base on certain column value (basically trying to loop a lookup until no further column can be updated)

I have the following:

```
df = the huge dataframe (1K to 10K+ rows x 51 cols)

has_update = True
while has_update:
   has_update = False

   for_procdf = df.loc[df['Incident Group ID'] == '-']

   for i, row in for_procdf.iterrows():
       #Check if the row's parent ticket id is an existing ticket id in the bigger df
       resultRow = df.loc[df['Ticket ID'] == row['Parent Ticket ID']]
       resultCount = len(resultRow.index)
       if resultCount == 1:
           IncidentGroupID = resultRow.iloc[0]['Incident Group ID']
           if IncidentGroupID != '-':
               df.at[i, "Incident Group ID"] = IncidentGroupID
               has_update = True
```

When I execute the script, an error occurs with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sdm.etl.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "./sdm.etl.py", line 28, in main
    fillIncidentGroupID(sdmdf.df)
  File "./sdm.etl.py", line 47, in fillIncidentGroupID
    df.at[i, "Incident Group ID"] = IncidentGroupID
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2159, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2580, in _set_value
    series = self._get_item_cache(col)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2490, in _get_item_cache
    res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3096, in _box_item_values
    return self._constructor(values.T, columns=items, index=self.index)
AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T'
```

However creating a similar scenario returns no error

```
>>> qdf = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30], [10, 13, 17]], index=[0,1,2,3], columns=['Ab 1', 'Bc 2', 'Cd 3'])
>>> qdf
   Ab 1  Bc 2  Cd 3
0     0     2     3
1     0     4     1
2    10    20    30
3    10    13    17
>>>
>>> qdf1 = qdf.loc[qdf['Ab 1'] == 0]
>>> qdf1
   Ab 1  Bc 2  Cd 3
0     0     2     3
1     0     4     1
>>>
>>> for i, row in qdf1.iterrows():
...     qdf.at[i, 'Ab 1'] = 10
...
>>>
>>> qdf
   Ab 1  Bc 2  Cd 3
0    10     2     3
1    10     4     1
2    10    20    30
3    10    13    17
```

What seems to be the problem with my implementation?

Comment: AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T' is occur when the dataframe is being modified has duplicate column names.

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do here??

Comment: @Nihal, trying to loop a lookup in the same dataframe to update a column value (let say col A) base on another row's col value until no further "col A" value can be updated.. did i make sense? wew..

Comment: @Nihal, I don't have a duplicate column name in my dataframe though.

Comment: if you have large dataset, then you should not use itterrows or for loop. you can use `.apply` or `np.where`

Comment: can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: A sample input looks like this => df.at[242, 'Incident Group ID'] = 'AAA-YYYYMMDD-XXXX', and manually doing that also returns the same error. Expected output is that it would update the df specific cell to that assigned value.

Comment: @Nihal, you were right, the error was cased by a duplicate column name. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Found out that, [Nihal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7053679/nihal) is right, the error is caused by a duplicate column name. My dataframe was too big, that I accidentally had a duplicate column name. Everything works fine now. A little time away from the code, rest and eat made me see the duplicate column. Cheers!

Below are the columns of my dataframe. **"RCA Group ID"** has duplicate near the end.

```
['Incident Group ID', 'RCA Group ID', 'Parent Ticket ID', 'Ticket ID', ..., 'RCA Group ID', 'Is Sector Down', 'Relationship Type']
```

Answer (score 2):

> the error is caused by a duplicate column name

That was true in my case.

You can use the following function to quickly determine which column names are duplicates.

```
def get_duplicate_cols(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(df.columns).value_counts()[lambda x: x>1]
```

[Source](https://hackersandslackers.com/remove-duplicate-columns-in-pandas/)